# I defriended several people and I don't want them subscribed to me anymore

Tags: facebook

I defriended several people on facebook recently. I noticed when I go to my friends list they are still there and subscribed to me. How do I unsubscribe them?

Answer (score 8):

You can either block those people (which you do by going to their profile, clicking the icon that looks like a machine cog, in the top left corner and then clicking Block/Report which will lead to a box where you can block them).

Alternatively you can make people think they are still your friends and subscribed to you by adding them to a 'Restricted' group which you can do from the facebook home page. Along the left side of the News Feed, with all your Apps there is a section called 'LISTS', which, after clicking More will display a group called Restricted. The people in that group will not see any of your updates and in Profile Settings you can also make it so they can't see any Pictures etc. as well.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You have to block them. To do that, follow the instructions below.

> **[How do I block someone from subscribing to me?](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=147856365300974#How-do-I-block-someone-from-subscribing-to-me?)**
>
> If you don’t want a specific person to subscribe to you, you’ll need to [block](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=168009843260943) them from your account.

---

> **[How do I block someone?](http://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=168009843260943)**
>
> To block someone:
>
> 1. Click the account menu [image] at the top right of any Facebook page and choose **Privacy Settings**.
> 2. Find the Block Lists section and click **Manage Block Lists**.
> 3. Enter the name or email address of the person you want to block and click **Block**. People will **not** be notified when you block them.
>
> If you can’t find someone using this method, try going to the person’s profile (timeline) and selecting **Report/Block This Person** from the [image] dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't want these people to see stuff you post (even shared with the whole world), then you can block them. If you just leave them as subscribers, they will still only be able to view stuff that is set to a broader setting than friends only.